# Best practice to change table name in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model I wanna move into a namespace, and with that also rename the table to include the namespace name. What is the best practices to do so?

I use strong migrations in the project, and when trying to just do rename_table :[old_table_name], :[new_table_name] it won't allow it and instead give me this suggestion:

```
=== Dangerous operation detected #strong_migrations ===

Renaming a table that's in use will cause errors
in your application. A safer approach is to:

1. Create a new table. Don't forget to recreate indexes from the old table
2. Write to both tables
3. Backfill data from the old table to new table
4. Move reads from the old table to the new table
5. Stop writing to the old table
6. Drop the old table
```

Are there any other way? The table itself is not very used and only have have about 400 records.

Comment: The obvious other way is to ignore the warning and proceed anyways. However it would have taken you less time to just do what the gem is telling you to do then writing the question - especially if the table just has a tiny amount of data.

Answer (score -1):

You can just add namespace in your model, not in migrations.
I think this article will helpful for you https://blog.bullettrain.co/rails-model-namespacing/

Comment: The question clearly states "and with that also rename the table to include the namespace name". I think he's fully aware of the alternative.